# How to add a Stripe Payment Details description or Timeline note

Tags: stripe-payments

If possible, how can a **Stripe** *"Payment Details description"* or a "Timeline note" be provided on `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`?

```
stripe.
    .confirmCardPayment( secret, {
        payment_method: { card }
    })
```

Comment: You would pass a `description` or `metadata` on your backend server when creating the PaymentIntent(not client side using confirmCardPayment). https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-description

Comment: @karllekko Thank you for the clarification.